# SQL list number of seen occurrences per month higher than 15

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm not an SQL expert, so I'm requesting your help to list the MACs that apear more than 15 days in a month.

I made the following query, but is very complex and most probably not efficient. Any suggestions on how to make it simpler and efficient?
I'm using Google BigQuery, if that helps.

```
SELECT
  macDays.macAddress AS macAddress,
  macDays.days AS days
FROM (
  SELECT
    list_mac.macAddress AS macAddress,
    COUNT( list_mac.macAddress) AS days
  FROM (
    SELECT
      macAddress,
      TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(time, DAY) date,
    FROM
      `my_table`
    WHERE
      time BETWEEN '2021-06-01 00:00:00'
      AND '2021-06-30 23:59:00.000059'
    GROUP BY
      macAddress,
      date
    ORDER BY
      macAddress) AS list_mac
  GROUP BY
    macAddress ) AS macDays
WHERE
  macDays.days > 15
GROUP BY
  macAddress,
  days
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are stripping off the time component from the date in your `SELECT` but grouping with the time portion left in, so you will get one row for every appearance rather than one for every day.

You can probably get rid of the inner subquery by using `COUNT(DISTINCT field)`.

Try something like:

```
SELECT
  macAddress AS macAddress,
  COUNT(DISTINCT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(time, DAY)) AS days
FROM 
  `my_table`
WHERE
  time BETWEEN '2021-06-01 00:00:00'
  AND '2021-06-30 23:59:00.000059'
GROUP BY
  macAddress
HAVING 
  COUNT(DISTINCT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(time, DAY)) > 15
ORDER BY
  macAddress
```

Comment: Great! much cleaner ... wasn't aware of the "HAVING" statement ;-)
One more question, if I also want to know the number of occurrences of a MAC per day and filter for more than 10, how can I do it?

Comment: I assume this is a different query. For your fields have `SELECT macAddress, TIME_STAMPTRUNC(time, DAY)) AS day, COUNT(*) as occurences` then group like `GROUP BY macAddress, TIME_STAMPTRUNC(time, DAY)) HAVING COUNT(*) > 10)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a subquery. It will calculate how many times a MAC exist in a day. Then it will pick only those appeared more than 15times in a month.
I have not used any filter so you can add filter as and when needed. If you need how many times MACs appear in database in a single day, you can use `dt` as group by. And if you want how many total MACs exists in whole month, just remove `distinct`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt,
       MAC,
       mnth
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT -- This will select only unique MACs on a day
 macAddress,
 TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIME, DAY) dt,
 TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIME, MONTH) mnth,
   FROM `my_table`) q
GROUP BY Mnth
HAVING COUNT(*)>15
```

Answer (score 0):

would go with [HAVING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp), which performs filtering to columns aggregated via `group by`:

```
select substr(time, 0, 8) yrmonth, macAddress, count(*) macDays
from my_table
where yrmonth = '2021-06'
group by macAddress, substr(time, 0, 8)
having count(*) >= 15
order by yrmonth desc
```

have not tried for GoogleBigQuery, here is the example on SQLite: [SQL Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/8910a/9)